# TFS Contribute permission for Git branch

Tags: git, tfs

We have on-premise Team Foundation Server (v14.114.26403.0). I am in the process of trying to lock down our dev+master branches to encourage devs to create feature branches and do pull requests to dev. As part of this I have set the Contribute permission to "Deny" for all access groups on dev branch except Project and Build Administrators groups.

Unfortunately once I do this members of the administrator groups cannot complete the pull requests, it looks like they don't have permission either, even though they explicitly have "Allow".

They get the following error:

> TF401027: Your account lacks the permission(s)
>   required for the operation you are attempting. You need to have
>   'GenericContribute'. Please contact your administrator.

I also get this error until I restore the contribute permissions to the other groups.

Anyone know why this is happening? Or how to resolve? All I can think of is that the users in administrator groups are also in contributors so perhaps the "Deny" from their membership to Contributor group is overriding their "Allow" from admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit "Deny" permissions are higher priority than explicit "Allow" permissions. In general, do not use explicit Deny. If a permission is *not* allowed (i.e. 'not set'), it is implicitly denied.

However, security settings are a bad solution to the scenario you're describing. You should be using [branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=vsts) to enforce pull requests. With a branch policy in place, the protected branch(es) can **only** be updated via a pull request, unless a user is granted permissions to allow them to ignore branch policies.

Comment: Great steer on the branch policies approach, was exactly what I was looking for. And the explicit Deny/Allow stuff was also useful, so a double whammy!